# How to Create And Display a Custom Sheet in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

This is a newbie question!

**How to Create And Display a Custom Sheet in Cocoa?** (like "Add Bookmark" sheet in Safari - see below)

- What are the steps involved in the task?
- How to accomplish each step?
- Can you point out a good step-by-step article?

[alt text http://grab.by/2oWw](http://grab.by/2oWw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is make a nib file containing an NSWindow that you want to use as the sheet, and load it up.  Check out [Using Custom Sheets](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html) in the docs.

`NSApplication` has a method to let you load the sheet up:

```
beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:
```

[This page](http://www.cats.rwth-aachen.de/library/programming/cocoa) has some more information and what I'd consider an easier way to set up the sheet - making it a panel or window inside the same nib file as your document window.